# Create check-in link for facebook

Tags: facebook, qr-code, checkin, facebook-checkins

I've tried to find a direct link to a check-in box in facebook.

This is the code that I found, on https://touch.facebook.com/Scoutsgroep.VZW.De.zwaluw/, I have tried to put the code on a website (wordpress) but that doesn't create a direct link to check*in on the page.

```
<a class="_55i1 _58a0 touchable" data-store="{&quot;action&quot;:&quot;\/page\/checkin\/?id=315057520648&quot;,&quot;inputname&quot;:&quot;status&quot;,&quot;targetid&quot;:1093893470,&quot;pagename&quot;:&quot;Scoutsgroep VZW de zwaluw&quot;,&quot;pageid&quot;:315057520648,&quot;placeholder&quot;:&quot;What are you doing?&quot;,&quot;composertitle&quot;:&quot;Check In&quot;,&quot;pinplace&quot;:true,&quot;forceasync&quot;:true,&quot;log_data&quot;:{&quot;under_more_button&quot;:true,&quot;page_id&quot;:315057520648,&quot;source&quot;:null,&quot;referrer&quot;:null,&quot;platform&quot;:&quot;mtouch&quot;},&quot;event_name&quot;:&quot;tapped_check_in&quot;,&quot;module_name&quot;:&quot;pages_public_view&quot;,&quot;nativeClick&quot;:true}" href="#" role="button" data-sigil="touchable touchable page_checkin m-pages-log-event"><span class="_55sr">Check In</span></a>
```

Later on I would like to use the created link to make a qr-code that automaticaly checks-in to the facebook page

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no direct link for a check in.  Facebook doesn't want people accidentally / maliciously being checked in to a place.

I suggest that you use the URL you have, put it into a QR code and let the user decide whether they want to check in.